# Import HTTPS HTML Table URL content to a mySQL Table

Tags: c#, html, mysql, import

I have an HTTPS URL that I can call to bring back results in an HTML formatted table but the values are updated every 10 minutes or so. I also have a mySQL DB and I've created a table to import this data into from the URL as:

```
CREATE TABLE `LogDB`.`HistLogs` (

    `Id` TINYINT NOT NULL,
    `TimeInt` INT NOT NULL,

    `TimeStr` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `IsVal` TINYINT NOT NULL,

    `MainVal` DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL,
    `QVal` TINYINT NOT NULL);
```

Here's the link to a screen print of the table with some values that come back from the call to the URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN0LR.png.

I need to make this call every 9 minutes or so and import the values from this table into a mySQL table but I cannot figure out what's the best C# method to do such a task if this is even possible.

I guess I'm asking if anyone has any experiencing with C# and doing a call to the URL and using WebClient, OpenRead, StreamReader, etc. to get the table data from the HTML table and turn around and insert these values into a mySQL table? If so, I'm wondering if someone from provide me a pointer to get me started or some simple example syntax, etc.

I have no problem explicitly defining table columns to insert data into so I'm willing to try anything at this point to get me going past my brain freeze stuck moment here.

So I have:

- URL that brings back HTML table (see link example)

  - Refreshes every 10 minutes
- A local mySQL DB that I need to insert the URL HTML table values into

  - Will run the import operation every 9 minutes but not import duplicates

I have tried various things from the Internet in my visual studio and I am not even close to getting this so I was just wondering if anyone could give me some more clear pointers from a C# rookie perspective with novice level experience to help me get a good starting point to move forward.